# updating observable in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to update a value and pass it inside another component. This is the in my service

```
  public useCashback = false;

  setUseCashback() {
    console.log(this.useCashback);
    this.useCashback = !this.useCashback;
    console.log(this.useCashback);
  }

  getUseCashback(): Observable<Boolean> {
    return observableOf(this.useCashback);
  }
```

inside my component I simply call setUseCashback to reverse the true or false

```
onUseCashback() {
    this.checkoutService.setUseCashback();
  }
```

then in another component I want to receive it when it is updated

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.useCashback = this.checkoutService
      .getUseCashback()
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
      });
```

so basically it get updated inside `setUseCashback` and I saw that by logging the useCashback variable but this doesn't respond inside my component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Subject to make it observable. In this case the BehaviorSubject lets you initialise it with a given value.
Quick update on your code:

```
public useCashback: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

```
setUseCashback(): void {
  const currentUseCashback = this.useCashback.getValue();
  this.useCashback.next(!currentUseCashback);
}
```

```
getUseCashback(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.useCashback.asObservable();
}
```

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.checkoutService.getUseCashback().subscribe((useCashback) => {
        this.useCashback = useCashback;
    });

 }
```